# How to use plugin content-events on featured contacts page

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin-events, com-contacts

Using the content event `onContentPrepare()` within a plugin in the contexts of '**com_contact.category**' and '**com_contact.contact**' works fine.

But the following code doesn't output anything on a page which is showing the **Contacts » Featured Contacts**:

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0) {
  var_dump($context);
}
```

If would expect something like e.g. `com_contact.featured`.

Also `onContentBeforeDisplay()` and `onContentAfterDisplay()` doesn't work.

Do i have a chance to get a content-plugin work within alle three events on the featured contact-page?

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and found a solution using template overrides (thanks to [Sharky answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24212/13129)).

You can manually [trigger content plugins](https://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension) in template overrides for **featured contacts** as well.

### Default template

Path: `/templates/<template>/html/com_contact/featured/default.php`

Run the content plugins on **some text**:

```
echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', 'For example mail like mail@domain.de are cloaked.');
```

Or run content plugins on a **custom context** like "com_contact.featured":

```
$featured = new stdClass;
$featured->text = 'For example mail like mail@domain.de are cloaked.'; // add text
$featured->params = new JObject; // add more to parameters if needed
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
JFactory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onContentPrepare', array ('com_contact.featured', &$item, &$item->params, 0));
```

### Default Items template

Path: `/templates/<template>/html/com_contact/featured/default_items.php`

Run the content plugins on **each item**:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
foreach($this->items as $item) {
  $app->triggerEvent('onContentPrepare', array ('com_contact.contact', &$item, &$item->params, 0));
}
```

Note that the context 'com_contact.contact' is used.

Answer (score 0):

No, plugin events are not triggered on Featured Contacts page. You can request this feature on the [Issue Tracker](https://issues.joomla.org/). Until this is implemented in core, you can only manually add the events in layout overrides.

Comment: Thank you @Sharky. What do you mean exactly with "add the events in layout overrides": Is it possible to trigger events in layout overrides?

Comment: Yes, it's done with `JFactory::getApplication()->triggerEvent()`. But doing anything in the layout is for your personal use only. If you want to create a plugin that can be used on other sites, this needs to be implemented in core first.